# How to simplify an exponentional equation?

Tags: exponential-function

Is it the best way for the expression of this equation:

$$x = \frac{yexp\big(z(t_1 - t_2)\big)}{1+exp\big({z(t_1 - t_2)}\big)}$$

Comment: What is your question about this expression?

Comment: Suppose all real, then  $\quad z=\dfrac{\log x-\log (y-x)}{t_1-t_2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x = y\sigma(z(t_1-t_2))$$

where $\sigma$ is the sigmoid function.

$$
\sigma(t) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-t}}
$$